# Access Database Tables

Tags: microsoft-access

I have taken over responsibility for an access database not designed by me that I need to clean up.  I have a table that I need to find out how it is calculating data.  I can't find that it is based on a query and when I click on relationships, it says it has no dependencies.  However, this information is not manually input.  It is a total of amounts for a certain UPI code (package) that include certain service codes.  (The UPI codes and what service codes are linked to them are part of another table).  The amounts come from another table that includes service codes.  When I run a pivot table on the data I cannot match the number in this table.....so I would like to find out what service codes this calculation is using.  Any ideas?

Comment: have you looked at the Design View of the tables?  Can you provide some structure info (eg fields, foreign keys) of the database?  What version of access?

Comment: Or perhaps the vba modules? there could be some logic tucked away in a module, if the database has them...

Comment: Some things to note, The "Relationships" button is not going to show you what changes the table necessarily.  It will show foreign key relationships if they were setup, but will not show queries that modify the table data.  "Object Dependencies" will show append/make/ update queries that change the data in the table.  A query that Appends/updates/creates TableX will appear under "Objects that depend on me".